# TCAM carving question for Cisco Nexus 9396PX

Tags: cisco, network, cisco-nexus, tcam

TCAM carving question for Cisco Nexus 9396PX
I have Cisco Nexus 9396PX and configure for IPv4 with IPv4 RACL on SVI to block some basic traffic. Now i have configured IPv6 and trying to configure access-list but its saying you don't have TCAM space so i started looking around to see where i can borrow and this is what i have.

As per document i may need 512 slice for ipv6 doble-width.

**Question:**

can i combine two 256 to create 512?

what is IPV4 PACL (i don't know who is using it and how to find out if someone using it?)

I am using BFD on this switch ( does BFD using redirect tcam space?)

```
# show hardware access-list tcam region | exclude 0
                               IPV4 PACL [ifacl] size =  512
                             IPV4 Port QoS [qos] size =  256
                                IPV4 RACL [racl] size =  512
                       Egress IPV4 RACL [e-racl] size =  256
                                  Ingress System size =  256
                                   Egress System size =  256
                             Ingress COPP [copp] size =  256
                             Redirect [redirect] size =  512
                       NS IPV4 Port QoS [ns-qos] size =  256
                      NS IPV4 VLAN QoS [ns-vqos] size =  256
                       NS IPV4 L3 QoS [ns-l3qos] size =  256
 VPC Convergence/ES-Multi Home [vpc-convergence] size =  256
               Ingress ARP-Ether ACL [arp-ether] size =  256
                       ranger+ IPV4 QoS [rp-qos] size =  256
                  ranger+ IPV6 QoS [rp-ipv6-qos] size =  256
                    ranger+ MAC QoS [rp-mac-qos] size =  256
                               sFlow ACL [sflow] size =  256
```

IPv6 has zero allocation

```
# show hardware access-list tcam region | grep IPV6
                          IPV6 PACL [ipv6-ifacl] size =    0
                        IPV6 Port QoS [ipv6-qos] size =    0
                  FEX IPV6 PACL [fex-ipv6-ifacl] size =    0
                FEX IPV6 Port QoS [fex-ipv6-qos] size =    0
                           IPV6 VACL [ipv6-vacl] size =    0
                       IPV6 VLAN QoS [ipv6-vqos] size =    0
                           IPV6 RACL [ipv6-racl] size =    0
                    Egress IPV6 QoS [e-ipv6-qos] size =    0
                    Egress IPV6 VACL [ipv6-vacl] size =    0
                  Egress IPV6 RACL [e-ipv6-racl] size =    0
                        IPV6 L3 QoS [ipv6-l3qos] size =    0
                  NS IPV6 Port QoS [ns-ipv6-qos] size =    0
                 NS IPV6 VLAN QoS [ns-ipv6-vqos] size =    0
                  NS IPV6 L3 QoS [ns-ipv6-l3qos] size =    0
                  ranger+ IPV6 QoS [rp-ipv6-qos] size =  256
```

This is what my utilization tables looks (its saying PACL used 3 does that means i can't take that slice?)

```
        ACL Hardware Resource Utilization (Mod 1)
         ----------------------------------------------------------
                                        Used    Free    Percent
                                                        Utilization
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ingress IPv4 PACL                       3       509     0.58
Ingress IPv4 Port QoS                   4       252     1.56
Ingress IPv4 RACL                       32      480     6.25
Egress IPv4 RACL                        3       253     1.17
SUP COPP                                214     42      83.59
SUP COPP Reason Code TCAM               8       120     6.25
Redirect                                7       505     1.36
Ingress Ether ACL                       15      241     5.85
VPC Convergence                         1       255     0.39
sFlow Northstar ACL                     0       256     0.00

LOU                                     2       22      8.33
Both LOU Operands                       2
Single LOU Operands                     0
LOU L4 src port:                        1
LOU L4 dst port:                        1
LOU L3 packet len:                      0
LOU IP tos:                             0
LOU IP dscp:                            0
LOU ip precedence:                      0
LOU ip TTL:                             0
TCP Flags                               0       16      0.00

Protocol CAM                            2       244     0.81
Mac Etype/Proto CAM                     0       14      0.00

L4 op labels, Tcam 0                    0       1023    0.00
L4 op labels, Tcam 2                    1       62      1.58
L4 op labels, Tcam 6                    0       2047    0.00
```

Comment: Have you read https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/119032-nexus9k-tcam-00.html ?

Comment: Yes i did read that because in google search only that link show ip for any kind of tcam search :)

Comment: TCAM allocation rules are very restrictive, not letting me use `ifacl` or `qos` slice for ipv6 or any other region. very limited options i have. I found middle ground for my solution so if it make sense then i will post in answer so it helps other folks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCAM has lots of restriction regarding region. `ifacl` and `qos` can't be used for IP slice so that is out of picture. now i have only following option left

**Redirect (512)** - BFD, DHCPv4/v6 used this slice.

**VACL (512)** - If you are not using any VLAN acl then this is good slice to take it.

**VPC (256)** - If you are not using vPC then another good slice.

This is what i did for workaround or you can say tradoff. I reduce redirect from `512` to `256` so i have choice to use `BFD/DHCP` in future.

```
 hardware access-list tcam region vacl 0
 hardware access-list tcam region redirect 256
 hardware access-list tcam region vpc-convergence 0
 hardware access-list tcam region ipv6-racl 512
```

Reboot your switch otherwise it will not work.